# Is it possible to create a trigger that creates another trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-insert, datatrigger

Is it possible to have a trigger that creates another trigger?

For example, I have `table_1` with a column `table_name`. On inserting into `table_1` the first trigger would create a trigger for the table inserted as `table_name`? I have not found much info on this.

Comment: What have you tried? Build the TSQL for the new trigger and create it using `sp_executesql`?

Comment: This has a really really bad smell to it.... I wouldn't design a system like that. Tables and their triggers should be handled by proper DDL scripts and be under your control - you shouldn't be creating tables (and triggers) dynamically upon an insert .....

Answer (score 0):

Trigger enables you to run dynamic SQL, in which you can create what objects you like, including other triggers (assuming you have the right permissions).

You can do that by using [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), it executes a Transact-SQL statement or batch that can be reused many times, or one that has been built dynamically. The Transact-SQL statement or batch can contain embedded parameters

This seems tough as a (very) bad design. So go ahead and try that (or not*).

*You can state your problem to begin with, may be in [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (if it's  more a design oriented question) or in [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), and you may get better help.